# Is Containing a Reference to the Calling or Containing Class Bad Encapsulation?

Tags: oop, encapsulation

I had a more general OOP question. Is it bad encapsulation to create a member that is a reference to the calling / containing class? For example:

```
class Foo
{
    void DoSomething()
    {
        Bar bar = new Bar(this);
    }
}
```

And in Bar.cs or Bar.cpp or wherever

```
public class Bar
{
    private Foo m_myFoo;
    public Bar(Foo foo)
      : m_myFoo(foo)
    {
    }
}
```

I just found myself needing to do this and wanted to know if this, in general, is a practice that smells of bad encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done is a form of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), by injecting Foo into Bar. We dont quite have enough info to see how you intend to use it, but it looks ok.

Instead of Encapsulation, I would be more concerned about the Coupling between the two classes.

You could instead consider creating the two classes separately and setting the foo reference on the bar instance.

Comment: I ended up not needing this because I thought of a more generic way to do this, however, my intention was only for Bar to be able to make a call to Foo since it is a Manager type class.